# CSS layout 3 toggleable columns 1 toggleable terminal-like footer

Tags: css, layout

Is there a cleaner/shorter way to achieve the same result with cross-browser CSS and using javascript only to toggle classes?

I'm trying to create a layout like the above but I've never tried to set everything absolutely as I did here so I don't know what might be the disadvantage.

```js
$(".left-col-content > .content").append(() => {
  return "left-col<br>".repeat(350);
});
$(".right-col-content > .content").append(() => {
  return "right-col<br>".repeat(350);
});
$(".terminal-row > .content").append(() => {
  return "terminal<br>".repeat(350);
});

$(".body-col-content > .content").append(() => {
  return "content<br>".repeat(350);  
});

$(".body-col-header > .content").append(() => {

  left_btn = $("<button>Toggle Left</button>").click(() => {
    $(".left-col").toggle();
    $(".body-col").toggleClass("left-hidden");
  });

  right_btn = $("<button>Toggle Right</button>").click(() => {
    $(".right-col").toggle();
    $(".body-col").toggleClass("right-hidden");
  });

  terminal_btn = $("<button>Toggle Terminal</button>").click(() => {
    $(".terminal-row").toggle();
    $(".main-row").toggleClass("terminal-hidden");
  });


  buttons = $("<div></div>")
    .append(left_btn)
    .append(right_btn)
    .append(terminal_btn);

  return buttons;

});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.container .main-row {
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0px;
}

.container .main-row.terminal-hidden {
  bottom: 0px;
}

.container .main-row .left-col {
  width: 150px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container .main-row .left-col .left-col-header {
  height: 50px;
  width: inherit;
  position: inherit;
  background-color: orange;
}

.container .main-row .left-col .left-col-content {
  width: inherit;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: inherit;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container .main-row .left-col .left-col-content .content {
  padding: 15px;
}

.container .main-row .right-col {
  width: 150px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container .main-row .right-col .right-col-header {
  height: 50px;
  width: inherit;
  position: inherit;
  background-color: orange;
}

.container .main-row .right-col .right-col-content {
  width: inherit;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: inherit;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container .main-row .right-col .right-col-content .content {
  padding: 15px;
}

.container .main-row .body-col {
  right: 150px;
  left: 150px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
}

.container .main-row .body-col.right-hidden {
  right: 0px;
}

.container .main-row .body-col.left-hidden {
  left: 0px;
}

.container .main-row .body-col .body-col-content {
  width: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: inherit;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container .main-row .body-col .body-col-content .content {
  padding: 25px;
}

.container .main-row .body-col .body-col-header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: inherit;
  background-color: red;
}

.container .terminal-row {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  color: green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container .terminal-row .content {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="main-row">
    <div class="left-col">
      <div class="left-col-header">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="left-col-content">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-col">
      <div class="right-col-header">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-col-content">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body-col">
      <div class="body-col-header">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="body-col-content">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="terminal-row">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This can be done with one line of javascript and flexbox. Your CSS structure is making things rather complicated. Simplify, simplify, simplify is always a good idea. I am creating a little outline source for you so you an see what I mean. Hold on for a while....

Comment: fantastic, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not fully finished yet, but will give you a frame you can use to work with.
As you can see in the snippet, I have used very rarely used properties of the `<style>` tag namely `id` and in javascript `.disabled`.

As style tags use and comply to W3 **'Global HTML Attributes'** rules [w3schools.com: HTML style tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp) you can simply give them an `#id` and toggle them en/disabled with a simple line of javascript.

As you can see in the Snippet I have defined all major elements as Flexbox Containers with some very generic `top/bottom/center/middle` classes to get the structure you want/need, leaving you with all the room you might need to specific stuff like spacing, fontsizing create you own #id's, etc.

Comment back when you need more info. (don't forget to close the question if you did get the answer you needed.)

In the code you can see that I first disabled the columns and drawer with `display: none`, each in its own `style` block.
Then I define them visible with `display: flex` (as they are flexbox `div's`) and enable/disable that style block on request by toggling it `enabled/disabled` with simple javascript.

```js
function toggleStyle(id) { var el = document.getElementById(id); el.disabled = !el.disabled }
```

```html
<style>
body                        { margin: 0 }

header,footer,main,section,item,
div                         { display: flex }

header,footer,section,div   { flex-direction: row    }
main,item                   { flex-direction: column }
header,footer,item,div      { flex-wrap: wrap }


header                      { min-height: 3.5rem } /* 3.5 * 16px */
footer                      { min-height: 2.5rem }

main                        { height: 100vh; justify-content: space-between }
section                     { height: 100%;  justify-content: space-between }
.drawer                     { align-content: space-between }


.left,.right                { width: 12.5% }
.center                     { flex: 1 }
.middle                     { flex: 1; width: 100% }
.top,.bottom                { height: 2rem; width: 100% }

.center-col                 { flex: 1 }

* { outline: 1px dashed }
</style>

<style>.drawer.left   { display: none }</style>
<style>.drawer.bottom { display: none }</style>
<style>.drawer.right  { display: none }</style>

<style id="stl-left-col" >.drawer.left   { display: flex }</style>
<style id="stl-terminal" >.drawer.bottom { display: flex }</style>
<style id="stl-right-col">.drawer.right  { display: flex }</style>

<body>
<main>
    <header>
        <input type="button" onclick="toggleStyle('stl-left-col')"  value="left column">
        <input type="button" onclick="toggleStyle('stl-terminal')"  value="terminal row">
        <input type="button" onclick="toggleStyle('stl-right-col')" value="right column">
    </header>

    <section class="content">
        <item class="drawer left">
            <div class="top"   >left top   </div>
            <div class="middle">left middle</div>
            <div class="bottom">left bottom</div>
        </item>

        <item class="content center">
            <div class="top">main top</div>
            <div class="middle">main middle
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">main bottom</div>
        </item>

        <item class="drawer right">
            <div class="top"   >right top   </div>
            <div class="middle">right middle</div>
            <div class="bottom">right bottom</div>
        </item>
    </section>
    
    <footer class="drawer bottom">some footer</footer>
</main>
</body>
```

Comment: is this going to work on IE9/IE10? If not is there a known way to make it work easily? I was hoping to have something working on IE9, this was way I was going for 'cross-browser" CSS.

Comment: Good question, I have no idea, but I believer there are polyfills for Flexbox. I use W10 and android so I can't test it. The Style enable/disable should work.

Comment: I'm testing it right now I'll let you know as soon as I have a tested result :)

Comment: I did take my time to test flexbox polyfills but I couldn't find one that worked nicely. That said I tried it and on newer browsers it works just awesomely unfortunately I still have a problem for IE9/IE10... Woudn't you be able to show me a solution compatible by default with older browsers?

Comment: Willing to help you with this, but then I have to know what of my snippet does not work on older browsers as installing IE9 would probably mess up my PC.

Comment: Also, I hope you figured out by now, that CSS rules are read sequentially so the last rule in the list will be applied. AND as you have separate `style` block, you can en/disable much more that just `display`. Fiddle with this a lot!!!

Comment: I'm also done with a decent solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/pinkynrg/3ymbsLgt/. This doesn't work since in IE9 overflow: hidden works only if the height has been defined. In the above example I did set the left/right/center container absolutely position to the main container left/right/center. So i decided to try to set the height using calc so ie9 is happy, but it doesn't seem to work.